# How do I display a view above all others?

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller

I want to display a modal view when the user shakes the phone. I was trying self.tabbarcontroller presentModal... but this won't work in cases where there is already a modal view open (Case: User is clicking around, and he clicks something that opens a modal view controller. Now, the user shakes his/her phone - should display a modal view on top of everything else now.).

Basically, what I want to do is display a view on top of all the other open views. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the view to the main application window. That will overlay the whole view hierarchy below it.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *viewOnTop = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

applicationDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDel.window addSubview:viewOnTop];
```